# Reverse /dev/null

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I am writing a program and needed to momentarily silence the output. I went online and found the solution was the following:

`./program > /dev/null`

I now need to see the output, but have not found a way to do so. After looking for it online, I now understand that what I'm basically doing is sending the output to a 'black hole', and I believe what I need to do is send the output of the program back to the *Standard Output*.

I've tried:

```
./program >1
./program >stdout
./program /dev/null>1
./program /dev/null>stdout
```

but still cannot get it to work. Does anybody know a possible solution?

Comment: have you tried `./program` only without `>...`?

Comment: Yes I have, but still no output is printed.

Answer (score 6):

You can't get back the previous output.  But just running the program normally will produce output to `stdout`...

```
./program
```

---

The `>` ('redirection' operator), redirects the output of the program *while it is running* to the target file (or stream).  You don't need to 'undo' or 'reverse' this in subsequent runs.  [Wikipedia has a great overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I've tried running the program as normal, but no output is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You have stated twice that your program without redirection on the command line produces no output.  So the problem is your program, not the redirection.

Also note that :

```
./program /dev/null>1
./program /dev/null>stdout
```

Both of these, which you tried, pass "/dev/null" as an *argument* to your application and apply redirection to that.

If you want to output to *both* stdout and a file using redirection you need a **tee** command.

You would use something like :

```
./program | tee mylogfiletxt
```

The '|' is a pipe between the output of program and the input of the tee application.  *tee* will send a copy of its input to stdout *and* the file you name.